# scan-line filling, differentiating between intersection points and peaks

Tags: java, algorithm, polygon, fill, scanline

I'm applying the scan-line algorithm to fill in a randomly generated continent-like shape. The main problem I'm having is when the line intersects a point that is a tip. I created some images to help visualize this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlbI5.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RACF1.png

I basically need help figuring out how to differentiate if an intersection point is a "tip" or not. Like in the first image, since both are tips, I end up with a line in between them, even though the line is outside of the continent-shape.

Comment: What is the second image? What you are currently getting?

Comment: with the second image, I get a line drawn from the first blue point to the last blue point. So i get the interior part filled but the exterior segment before it is filled as well.

Comment: If your lines are just pixels, you're screwed.  You have to flood-fill. If your lines are part of a polygon representation, then a single vertex in that polygon represents an intersection with two edges.  Should cause no problem -- if the two edges are on the same side of the scanline, you treat it as two edges.  Otherwise you treat it as one.

Comment: what do you mean by "on the same side of the scan line?"

Answer (score 1):

try checking to the immediate left and the right of the intersection. If they're both below the red line, than it's a tip.

That's the best i can do without knowing more about how the lines are defined.

Comment: the lines start from the top most point of the shape, and are one pixel thick. I draw a line from left to right sides of the image, and look at all of the intersection points. Then using those intersections, I draw a line to fill the interior. After that, I move one pixel down until repeat the same process until i reach the lowest point of the shape

Comment: @user1801501 well if the lines are defined pixel by pixel, than yeah, you'd have to look one pixel to the left and one pixel to the right.